# Using fileinput.input() to read gzip files

Tags: gzip, file-io

I'm using fileinput to read some large data:

```
import gzip
import fileinput
f=gzip.open('/scratch/try.fastq.gz','r')
for line in fileinput.input(f):
    print line
```

However I got errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/share/lib/python2.6/fileinput.py", line 253, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "/share/lib/python2.6/fileinput.py", line 345, in readline
    self._file = open(self._filename, self._mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '@HWI-ST150_0129:2:1:13466:2247#0/1\n'
```

Cannot fileinput take file object as input? Then how to use fileinput to deal with gzip file?
thx

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the first argument to `fileinput.input` should be a list of filenames. What you want can be achieved with

```
for line in gzip.open('/scratch/try.fastq.gz')
    print line
```

`fileinput` exists to support the idiom where a program reads from a list of files, probably supplied on the command line, or standard input if no files have been specified. If you still want to use it, even though it's useless in your example, you should do

```
for line in fileinput(['/scratch/try.fastq.gz'], openhook=gzip.open):
    print line
```

Comment: Here is my another post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454344/fileinput-usage-with-openbook-hook-compressed

Answer (score 0):

As other sources have said, the value for `openhook` must be a function, but that doesn't mean you can't call a function to return a function. For example, if you want to support multiple different types of incoming files you could write something like this:

```
import fileinput
import gzip

def get_open_handler(compressed):
    if deciding_data:
        # mode comes in as 'r' by defualt, but that means binary to `gzip`
        return lambda file_name, mode: gzip.open(file_name, mode='rt')
    else:
        # the default mode of 'r' means text for `open`
        return open

# get args here

for line in fileinput.input(args.files, openhook=get_open_handler(args.compressed))
    print(line)
```

As you can see, we are calling a function from `openhook`, but that function returns another function. In this case, we are fixing the `mode` of `gzip.open`, but we can do anything we want, including using `functools.partial` to bind some values to a function so that when the default `filename` and `mode` get passed to the function assigned to `openhook`, the function will do what you want.